# Get [Display] attribute value from resource in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, data-annotations, html-helper

I have used the `[Display]` attribute for one of my enums:

```
    public enum eCommentType
    {
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FaultManagementStrings), Name = "NormalComment")]
        NormalComment = 0,

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FaultManagementStrings), Name = "OpenningComment")]
        OpenningComment = 1,

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FaultManagementStrings), Name = "StartProgressComment")]
        StartProgressComment = 2,

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FaultManagementStrings), Name = "ClouserComment")]
        ClouserComment = 3,

        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(FaultManagementStrings), Name = "ReopennignComment")]
        ReopennignComment = 4
    }
```

Is it possible to create an Extention method that will reuse the exsisting MVC finctionallity of getting the Display attribute value from the specified resource ?

I would what something like that...

```
@Html.GetEnumDisplayAttributeValue(c=> comment.CommentType)
```

I know i could wirte something that will implement the required reflection and find the value of the resource type and the call resource manager and so on... but i think that maybe it is possible to use the exsisting built in functionally of mvc.. after all it is already done when you call a `LabelFor` helper.

is is possible or should i reinvent the wheel ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have had the same problem and created these extension methods:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

public static class EnumHelper
{
    private static readonly SelectListItem[] SingleEmptyItem = new[] { new SelectListItem { Text = string.Empty, Value = string.Empty } };

    public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression)
    {
        return htmlHelper.EnumDropDownListFor(expression, null);
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString EnumDropDownListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var enumType = GetNonNullableModelType(metadata);
        var values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TEnum>();

        var items =
            values.Select(value => new SelectListItem
                                       {
                                           Text = GetName(value),
                                           Value = value.ToString(),
                                           Selected = value.Equals(metadata.Model)
                                       });

        if (metadata.IsNullableValueType)
        {
            items = SingleEmptyItem.Concat(items);
        }

        return htmlHelper.DropDownListFor(expression, items, htmlAttributes);
    }

    private static string GetName<TEnum>(TEnum value)
    {
        var displayAttribute = GetDisplayAttribute(value);

        return displayAttribute == null ? value.ToString() : displayAttribute.GetName();
    }

    private static DisplayAttribute GetDisplayAttribute<TEnum>(TEnum value)
    {
        return value.GetType()
                    .GetField(value.ToString())
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
                    .Cast<DisplayAttribute>()
                    .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private static Type GetNonNullableModelType(ModelMetadata modelMetadata)
    {
        var realModelType = modelMetadata.ModelType;
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(realModelType);

        return underlyingType ?? realModelType;
    }
}
```

You can use these extension methods in your views as follows:

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(c=> comment.CommentType)
```

You should now see a dropdownlist containing the enum values' names according to their `DisplayAttribute`.

The actual retrieval of the displayed enum value is done in the `GetName` method, which first uses the `GetDisplayAttribute` method to try to retrieve the `DisplayAttribute` of the enum value. If the enum value was indeed decorated with a `DisplayAttribute`, it will use that to retrieve the name to be displayed. If there is no `DisplayAttribute`, we just return the name of the enum value.

Comment: can you be more specific ? what method exactlly responsible for extracting the information from the display attribute and the resource ?

Comment: @Mortalus I have just updated the description. What you should be looking into are the `GetName` and `GetDisplayAttribute` methods, which are use to extract the display attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As was to be expected, Microsoft included an `EnumDropDownListFor` HTML Helper method in [MVC 5.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/09/asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-2-preview-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx) (RC1).